# sudo command allows for successful create-react-app, but my user already has admin access

Tags: npm, sudo, create-react-app, macos-high-sierra

I'm pretty new to macOS. As the title says, when I run create-react-app using npm out of the terminal, it fails with this error:

```
Aborting installation.   
npm install --save --save-exact react react-dom react-scripts has failed
```

Running this with sudo results in the command being successful, and the React app being created. What I do not understand is why sudo is working? The user I'm logged in as is an admin, so I think I don't fully understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

### You need to reinstall NPM to use it without sudo.

First check what to reinstall later globally:

```
npm list -g --depth=0
```

Tell npm to install packages to home:

```
npm config set prefix ~/npm
```

#### Change your paths:

Open your .bashrc (Linux):

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

for Mac

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

add these lines at the end:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/npm/bin"
export NODE_PATH="$NODE_PATH:$HOME/npm/lib/node_modules"
```

save the file and then enter this command to make the changes take effect:

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

or

```
. ~/.bash_profile
```

Take ownership of everything in your ~/.npm directory (must be run with sudo):

```
sudo chown -R $USER:`id -g -n $USER` ~/.npm
```

After all, you can install globally without sudo. Ex:

```
npm install -g live-server
```

Or, create react app with:

```
npm init react-app <your reactapp>
```